# Subtract 1 from column based on another DataFrame. Pandas

Tags: pandas

Trying to figure out how to subtract a constant from a column based on the presence of a value in another DataFrame. For example, if I have the below DataFrame `a` that contains a column called `person` name and `count`:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({
      "person":["Bob", "Kate", "Joe", "Mark"],
      "count":[1, 2, 3, 4],
    })
   person  count
0  Bob     3
1  Kate    4
2  Joe     5
2  Mark    4
```

And a second DataFrame that contains `Person` and whatever other arbitrary columns:

```
b = pd.DataFrame({
      "person":["Bob", "Joe"],
      "foo":['a', 'b'],
    })
   person  foo
0  Bob     a
1  Joe     c
```

My hope is that I can change the first DataFrame to look like the below. Specifically decreasing `count` by one for any instance of `person` within DataFrame `b`. It is safe to assume that DataFrame `b` will always be a subset of DataFrame `a` and  `person` will be unique.

```
   Person  Count
0  Bob     2
1  Kate    4
2  Joe     3
2  Mark    4
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: IIUC, in the output `Joe` should have 4 instead of 3, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a["count"] -= a.person.isin(b.person)
```

With `isin` we get a boolean array of `True` and `False`s per each person if it is in the other one or not. Then treating it as integers, we can subtract it from `count` column,

to get

```
>>> a

  person  count
0    Bob      2
1   Kate      4
2    Joe      4
3   Mark      4
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that `df2` can have multiple instances of a name. If it is just one instance, you can subtract by just iterating through and checking whether the person is named in the second data frame. In `df2`:

```
df2_counts = df2['Person'].value_counts()
```

In `df1`, join this data over and then subtract the counts:

```
df1['subtracts'] = df1.set_index('Person').join(df2_counts)
df1['count_new'] = df1['count'] - df1['subtracts']
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a list of person names from Dataset B:

```
listDFB=DFB['person']
```

loop through dfa to fill new col accordingly

```
for i, rw in dfa.iterrows():
    if rw['person'] in listDFB:
        rw['count']=rw['count']-1
```